# Lists not resetting after loop has been executed

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, raspberry-pi, serial-communication

I am trying create a loop that resets all the data inside of it every iteration but somewhere the data is not resetting even though I am initializing values inside of the loop.

Here is my code:

```
import time , sys , string
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600,
                   parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                   stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                   bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
                   )
print (ser.name)
ser.write(b'U')
#print ('test1')

time.sleep(2)

b=0
while (b <= 2):

    time.sleep(0.25)

    ser.write(b'R')
    #print ('test2')

    d = [] # establishes an empty list to iterate through all the incoming data
    i=0 # beginning of the buffer
    time.sleep(0.5)

    while (i<=11):
        d.append(str(ord(ser.read()))) #adding each incoming bit to the list
        #print (d[i])
        #print ('^ is the ' + str(i) + 'th term')  // these two lines help establish where the useful information begins for the lidar. 

        i+=1

    #establishing a better way to write the data out / gd = good distance
    gd = []
    a = 0
    for a in range(8):
        gd.append(str(chr(int(d[a+4]))))
    print (gd)

    print (gd[0] + gd[1] + gd[2] + gd[3] + gd[4] + gd[5] + gd[6] + gd[7] + ' mm')

    ser.flush()
    b+=1
```

The reason i do `d[a+4]` is because the first few bits of information are nonsense so I need it to start from that bit every time.

The program works in the first loop and correctly prints it out, however, in subsequent loops it begins to start from different points when I try to print out the values again. I am unsure if I am missing something and would love a second opinion.

My outputs are:

```
D = 0609 mm
\r:\rD = 0 mm
mm \r:\rD mm
```

so it's looping around the lists I'm creating somewhere and since it's taking in the string from the print statement I wonder if that has something to do with the issue.

Comment: 1) Can it happen that you should ignore those 4 bytes only for the very first "R" command?

Comment: 2) Is it sure that you read the entire response?

Comment: @tevemadar yes because the data in the first iteration is correct so I am trying to recreate it if things change in the incoming data.

Comment: @tevemadar and yes it would be fine to ignore the first few bits as I am only printing the data I am receiving.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment, so here is a little suggestion. At the end of your main loop, after

`b+=1`

add the following line

`d, gd = [], []`

if they are no longer useful after the loop has ended (which I suspect is the case). It'll reset any value the both variables hold in them and you'll be able to start from empty lists again.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, it still is reading things wrong after the first iteration. I wonder if the issue may be elsewhere in my data allocation.

Comment: Can you give an expected output in your edits? That can be helpful

Comment: I did! updated after you posted my apologies. I posted my exact output.

Comment: That is the output that your code is giving you, which as you are saying is correct to only first iteration. It means either, there is something wrong going on with the collection in `d` variable or your `gd` variable must be picking up wrong indices. What can help is two or three outputs of `d` so it can be tested against the correct output and optionally what you expect should be the second and third output of `gd` if that is possible.